# How to find immediate webelements inside particular webelement in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Below is my html code:

```
<div class="abc">
  <ul class="a">
    <li></li>
    <ul class="b">
  <ul class="c">
<div class="abcd">
  <ul class="d">
    <li></li>
```

I want to locate first **ul** element

> css locator would be = div.abc > ul

But I want to locate this element using below code:

```
final String firstUlElement = ">ul";

@FindBy(css = ".div.abc")
WebElement divElement;

List<WebElement> firstUlElement = this.divElement.findElements(By.cssSelector(firstUlElement));
```

But it throws following error:

```
The given selector >ul> is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
Command duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'PratikPat-w7', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=>ul}
Session ID: ba99cd84-0640-4af7-870a-50d79d893332
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

So how to locate first immediate element after div.abc using above code??
Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `>` when you are using `findElements()` on a `WebElement`. If you make this change it should work.

```java
final String firstUlElement = "ul";
```

**Note**: You are using `findElements()`. This will result in a list of elements and not just the first `ul`. Don't you mean to use `findElement()`?

Comment: If I don't use '>' then it will take all ul elements , but I need immediate child of 'div.abc'

Comment: This way it will find all `ul` that are a child of `div.abc`. As I said in the note using `findElements()` will return a list with all these elements. You only want the first so you should change this to `findElement()`

Comment: It would work fine but I want the hierarchy of `div.abc>ul` elements, because in DOM there are many `div.abc>ul` elements are available , I want the list of all that type of locators.. Thanks.

Comment: @PratikPatel Then I don't understand the problem. You are getting the list of elements you want to get. If you want the first one just get the first element for the list?

Comment: "You don't need to add > when you are using findElements() on a WebElement." This is not a correct statement. `>` means a child element (one level down). If you use `WebElement.findElements()` it will find any descendant... not just the immediate children. It's the equivalent of "abc cde" not "abc>cde". See https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors for more info.

Answer (score 1):

`divElement.findElements(By.cssSelector(firstUlElement));` will search for tag `>ul` under the `divElement`. There isn't such tag.

To search for immediate child using `>` you need to use the parent and identifiers together in the `cssSelector`

`By.cssSelector(div.abc > ul)`

Or using the `divElement`

```
final String firstUlElement = "ul";

@FindBy(css = "div.abc")
WebElement divElement;

WebElement firstElement = divElement.findElement(By.cssSelector(firstUlElement));
```

This will give you the first element it finds.

Note I removed the dot from `div.abc`. Dot represents a class, you can't use it on `<div>` tag.